# External table from current date directory

Tags: scala, apache-spark, databricks

External table creation from current date folder -- Scala

Hi, My data lake storage has directories which is in the following format yyyy/mm/dd and every day new directory for the current date gets created and a file for that date gets dropped in here. I need to point to only the current date directory to create external table. How can I do this? Any help is appreciated.

I tried creating variables for location like this

```
val s = java.time.LocalDate.now.toString
val year = s.slice(0, 4)
val month = s.slice(5,7)
val date = s.slice(8,10)
val location = "/mnt/mountdatalake/test/" + year + "/" + month + "/" + date + "/" + "*.txt"
```

and when i try to pass this location variable in external table it doesn't pull the data Any help on passing the variable into location parameter in external table will also be helpful

I tried it doing it this way first

```
sqlContext.sql(s"""CREATE table est.TEST_DATA(
ASSET string,
AREA_NAME string,
CCCC string
)
USING CSV   
OPTIONS (header='true',
delimiter = '|',
nullvalue='NA',
inferschema = 'true',
timestampFormat="yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss")
LOCATION '$location'""")

the second way is this

sqlContext.sql(s"""CREATE table est.TEST_DATA(
    ASSET string,
    AREA_NAME string,
    CCCC string
  )
USING CSV   
OPTIONS (header='true',
delimiter = '|',
nullvalue='NA',
inferschema = 'true',
timestampFormat="yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss")
LOCATION 'location'""")
```

Both of them did not work

Comment: at the very least, the location should point to a directory, i.e. NOT include `*.txt`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use a variable inside the triple quote, cap it with `${location}`.

```
val location = "/tmp/path/to/dir"

val query = s"""
CREATE table est.TEST_DATA(
    ASSET string,
    AREA_NAME string,
    CCCC string
)
USING CSV   
OPTIONS (header='true',
delimiter = '|',
nullvalue='NA',
inferschema = 'true',
timestampFormat="yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss")
LOCATION ${location}"""

print(query)
```

The result is as below.

```
CREATE table est.TEST_DATA(
    ASSET string,
    AREA_NAME string,
    CCCC string
)
USING CSV
OPTIONS (header='true',
delimiter = '|',
nullvalue='NA',
inferschema = 'true',
timestampFormat="yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss")
LOCATION /tmp/path/to/dir
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It worked for me. Another question to follow up, my folder has multiple files and i need to create an external table for each of the file. Is there a way i can dynamically do this rather than creating one location variable for each file

Comment: Location is not a file but has to be a directory I think. The external table will show all the data in that path from all files.

Comment: Yes, location has to be a directory. If that location has multiple files, can i dynamically create multiple external tables for each file there. I don't want to create one location variable for each file under that directory. Thank you

Comment: I don't understand. The location is a directory and you cannot create several external tables depending on each file. The location itself is 'a' table.